# What's the traditional song "don't be mean to your daughter in law..."

Tags: song-lyrics

[NPR](http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2016/08/28/489787912/japans-centuries-old-tradition-of-making-soba-noodles) has an article here.

The second audio named *Japan's Centuries-Old Tradition Of Making Soba Noodles* where apparently the song translates as

> Don't be mean to your daughter in law
>
> someday your daughter will
> marry and become a daughter in law herself

Comment: You want to know the title? Or the lyrics? -> There you go http://minyou.jugem.jp/?eid=36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title is [東祖谷]{ひがしいや}の[粉曳]{こひ}き[唄]{うた}

The lyrics of the part sung in the audio in your link:

> [嫁]{よめ}じゃ嫁じゃと　嫁のなしょたてなよ
>   かわい[我]{わ}が[子]{こ}も　[人]{ひと}の嫁よ　サーヨイヨイヨー
>
> [祖谷]{いや}と[言]{い}わずに　また[来]{き}てたもれよ
>   [手打]{てう}ち　そばなど　しんぜやすョ　サーヨイヨイヨー

You can find the lyrics of the whole song [here](http://minyou.jugem.jp/?eid=36).

Comment: Excellent. Any chance of a rough translation?

Comment: I think the first two lines say: "Stop finding faults with your daughter in law. Your own beloved child is also someone's daughter in law." and the 3rd and 4th: "Don't say '[祖谷]{いや}'(=pun for [嫌]{いや}; "No"), please visit us again. And we will serve you hand-made buckwheat noodles."

Comment: Which dialect is this? Kyoto-ben?

Comment: ^さあ・・・徳島県だから徳島弁とか四国弁とか？　多分ここ -> https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%B1%E7%A5%96%E8%B0%B7%E5%B1%B1%E6%9D%91 いや～、絶対京都弁じゃないｗ